How do I get unstuck?
I got stuck in a crevice on a mountain in Planet Crafter. How do I get unstuck and what happens or where do I go when I get unstuck?

Pressing the F4 key will float you above the current surface and allow you to get unstuck.
Repeated pressing the key will increase your altitude.
F4 also temporarily ignores collisions, so can be used to get to inaccessible areas if necessary (although that is considered by some to be cheating).
